# How to find headers included inside a namespace?

Tags: c++

I found a header included inside a namespace in the project I am working in. I want to scan the whole source base to find if this possible mistake was repeated in another file or not.

Is there a way using grep for example to do that?

Comment: It's not always a "mistake" to `#include` a header file inside a namespace. There are occasions where it might be useful.

Comment: As how to "solve" your problem, if the project is small and doesn't have many source or header files (say, less than 100 in total), you can just search for `#include` in your editor or IDE, and check each file individually.

Comment: I know this is not always a mistake, but I have to double check. The project is huge, and I really can't do it manually.

Comment: Besides i found an include of a std header inside of our own namespace which I believe is a mistake

Comment: If it is such a big project then you're probably not alone on it. The first choice should then be to go to the person who made the change (you do have a version control system which logs changes, right?) and ask him or her about it.

Comment: Yeah that is what I did. I want to track all other cases of this same problem.

Comment: What is the C++ ide/compiler you're working with?

Comment: Using gcc with vim. No IDE.